# How to handle / bind Angular signals with <input> of the html?

Tags: html, angular, input, signals

In my Angular app the variable value will be changed by a  HTML element <input> and two-way binding as

```
<input
    [(ngModel)]=variableName
    (OnKeyup)="DoSomething"
  >
```

But now [(ngModel)] will not work for signals.
Should it now the best praxis to use e.g. a (onKeyup) to start a function, which will excecute ... variableName.set(value).
And how to get the value and "sent" back to the input field value?

Comment: you don't have to use 2 way binding: `[ngModel]="someSignal()"` and `(ngModelChange)="someSignal.set($event)"` is the signal equivalent

Comment: Thank you for your quick and good reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried out a new way to test if using the 2 way bind would work.

```
<textarea class="license-textarea" rows="5" cols="30" pInputTextarea [(ngModel)]="vm.licenseKey"
                (input)="onLicenseKeyEntry($event)" placeholder="Enter license key"></textarea>
```

Using the computed signal along side with a get viewMode:

```
licenseKey: WritableSignal<string> = signal('');
  isLicenseValid: WritableSignal<boolean> = signal(false);
  protected readonly viewMode = computed(() => ({
    licenseKey: this.licenseKey(),
    isLicenseValid: this.isLicenseValid()
  }));
  get vm(): ReturnType<typeof this.viewMode> {
    return this.viewMode();
  }
```

Of course, this approach fits in my case. I just would like to share a alternative usage with the 2 way bind.

Answer (score 3):

This is the equivalent of `ngModel` in signals syntax!

```
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
  <input type="text"
        [ngModel]="quantity()"
        (input)="onQuantitySelected($any($event.target).value)"/>

        {{quantity()}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  quantity = signal<number>(1);

  onQuantitySelected(qty: number) {
    this.quantity.set(qty);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lsph4x)

---

#### References:

[medium article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/angular-signals/)